# This Android SDK requires ADT version 23.0.0 or above. Current version is 22.6. Please update ADT to the latest version?

Tags: android, eclipse, sdk

I downloaded and installed Eclipse ADT with android SDK for windows from  this website [Developer.Android](http://developer.android.com/sdk/index.html). When I try to Create AVD Device am getting error that `Location of Android SDK has not been setup in Preferences.` I open `Preferences` from `Windows`menu bar and then i try to set SDK Location but it showing error **This Android SDK requires ADT version 23.0.0 or above.  Current version is 22.6.  Please update ADT to the latest version.** How to update it ? help me to create android project.

Answer (score 95, accepted):

You can also update the ADT plugin

1. Select *Help* > *Install New Software*
2. *Work with:* `p2repo - https://dl-ssl.google.com/android/eclipse/`
3. Select *Developer Tools* and *Next*
4. *Next*, Accept the license agreement* and *Finish*

Comment: This is the right answer. Simply checking for updates does not work, but if you do as this answer suggests and check on the new version (for 23) then Eclipse knows to uninstall the old version an install thw new one

Comment: My installation doesn't automatically uninstall... it actually fails with a new error message saying it can't update ADT because it's not the latest version:

"Cannot complete the install because of a conflicting dependency."

Comment: If you have a conflict with the previous version:
1. Select Help > Install New Software 
2. Click on already installed
3. Select all Android software on version 22.*
4. Click on Uninstall
5. Work with: https://dl-ssl.google.com/android/eclipse/
6. Select Developer Tools and Next
7. Next, Accept the license agreement and Finish.

Comment: I cannot delete all the software because of dependencies. I had to remove software one by one. And restart ADT each time...

Comment: if you have the Eclpse ADT bundle installed and folllow @Kikiwa steps, then eclipse files will be deleted. Be careful

Comment: I should have read the last comment...:(

Comment: Unfortunately I did follow @Kikiwa steps on my bundle and now everything is gone, is there a way to quickly restore?

Comment: @Kikiwa's advice was what got me on the right path. If you're blocked from clicking Next due to other conflicts you may also have to remove other packages such as Tracer for OpenGL ES. I had to go back and forth several times before I removed all the incompatible packages.

Comment: It showing "Cannot complete the install because of a conflicting dependency.
  Software being installed: Android Development Tools 23.0.3.1327240 (com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.feature.feature.group 23.0.3.1327240)" ..any suggestion.

Comment: After uninstalling previous version (see above), I also had to uninstall Blackberry SDK because of another "conflicting dependency" error.

Comment: following @Kikiwa's advice broke my setup entirely and I can't open eclipse that came with the adt bundle.

Comment: @Kikiwa recommend that you edit or delete comment entirely.  your proposèd solution is too risky.without a DISCLAIMER.  ;)

Answer (score 17):

You can re-install them as follows:

Goto: Help--> About Eclipse SDK--> Installation Details.
select the plugins you want to uninstall

install them as:
Goto: Help--> Install new software

add https://dl-ssl.google.com/android/eclipse/

select the plugins to install.

Answer (score 4):

You have to update Your ADT Plugin. I everytime do it as administrator:

1. Select Help > Check for Updates.
2. In the resulting Available
   Updates dialog, locate the Android DDMS and Android Development
   Tools features in the list and ensure that the checkboxes next to
   them are selected. Click Next.
3. In the Update Details dialog, click Next.
4. Read and accept the license agreement and then click Finish. This will
   download and install the latest version of Android DDMS and
   Android Development Tools.
5. Restart Eclipse.

If it is not clear enough and some pictures will help You, see here:

http://theopentutorials.com/tutorials/android/updating-android-sdk-and-eclipse-adt-plugin/

Comment: It's quite clear, but it doesn't work. Eclipse still says "No updates were found." What a POS software.

Comment: so I think in Your case, the best way is to uninstall it and give it a new try step by step. I´ve stumpled often about such things in the beginning....

Comment: @Opiatefuchs but when you uninstall eclipse becomes invalid and cannot start any more.