# Target SDK not showing above 18 in eclipse

Tags: android, eclipse

When creating a new android project, the target SDK does not show above 18.  I have gone into the Android SDK Manager and updated everything up to version 21.  Now when I start eclipse it comes up with the error "The Android SDK requires Android Developer Toolkit version 23.0.o0 or above.  Current version is 22.3.0.   Please update ADT to the latest version.".

So I check for updates and then it tells me there are no updates found.  Has anyone else had this problem and know why possibly it finds no updates when it is specifying one needs to be made?

Also, I tried this link, [This Android SDK requires ADT version 23.0.0 or above. Current version is 22.6. Please update ADT to the latest version?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24491193/this-android-sdk-requires-adt-version-23-0-0-or-above-current-version-is-22-6).   The below gets me to install 23.0.0 but I keep getting dependency errors.  There is a comment to uninstall the 22.3.0 versions but if I take that route it completely uninstalls eclipse as well.   Text from that article below:

"You can also update the ADT plugin

Select Help > Install New Software 
Work with: p2repo - https://dl-ssl.google.com/android/eclipse/ 
Select Developer Tools and Next
Next, Accept the license agreement* and Finish"

**UPDATE:**  The quickest resolution I found to this, to at least be able to start a new project and target the newer SDKs, was to just download the newest Android SDK bundle.  This downloaded all of the latest that I needed.

Answer (score -1):

There can be many issue.Did you restart you eclipse.If not,try it.Your eclipse may be outdated.Eclipse should be kepler or mars or Your ADT didn't properly updated.So you have to update again from where it was.

Comment: I have closed and restarted eclipse.  I have been trying to update everything and am unable to get to the 23.0.0 version due to dependency issues.  If I uninstall all the 22 versions, then eclipse gets completely uninstalled.   Currently I am just installing the Android SDK bundle again.

Comment: No just uninstall 23,then restart eclipse then start again update.

Comment: There is no evidence that Eclipse's version is out of date. In any case version Mars is a future release, planned for release in June 2015

Comment: @HimanshuSaini - I can't uninstall 23 when I can't even get it installed in the first place.