# Import com.google.android.gms.location.LocationServices, can't update location services

Tags: android

I'm trying to test LocationService example as in http://developer.android.com/training/location/retrieve-current.html
I fall in error which is really similar to

[Can't Import com.google.android.gms.location.LocationServices](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25370598/cant-import-com-google-android-gms-location-locationservices)

but I can't resolve.

I installed Google play services which version (in my Android SDK Manager ) is 17. I know that latest release is 19 but I'm not able to update version from SDK manager, I can't find any options for doing so.

in my code:

```
import com.google.android.gms.location.LocationListener;
import com.google.android.gms.location.LocationRequest;
import com.google.android.gms.location.LocationServices;
```

first two are fine, third is getting:

> import.... cannot be resolved

Edit 12/1/2015

I'm using Eclipse.

Answer (score 16):

You need to compile Google Play Services library into your project.

If you're using AndroidStudio:

Open up `build.gradle` and to you `dependencies` tag add this:

```
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:6.+'
```

So it looks like:

```
dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:6.+'
}
```

---

With the new Play Services library you can selectively compile APIs (you might not need the whole library but just a part of it). You'd go for:

```
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:6.+'
```

More about selective compilation [here](http://developer.android.com/google/play-services/setup.html).

Comment: Thanks, i'm using Eclipse, I imported google library using **File >> Import >> Existing Android code into workspace** then i added  these library projects as dependencies to my project using  **Project properties**  . It is possible selectively compile Google Play Services library also in Eclipse? I'm a little bit confused...

Answer (score 1):

I solved my problem but I don't know exactly how...

First I run **Help >> Check for Updates**

After doing so I updated **Android SDK Tools** and **Android SDK Platform Tools** from SDK Manager, then  version of Google Play Services became 22 (before was 17).

My projects had then a red exclamation next to them... and an error saying

```
Google-play-services_lib Unable to resolve target 'android-9
```

I deleted google-play-services_lib from my Package Explorer, then re-add library using **Import >> Existing Android Code Into Workspace**

I don't know exactly wich operation solved the problem... i made so many attempts...

IMPORTANT

After updating SDK i came in an error saying

```
This Android SDK requires ADT version 23.0.0 or above.
```

so basically I uninstalled ADT (which version was 22.x) including:

- Android Traceview
- Android Hierarchy Viewer
- Android Development Tools
- Android DDMS
- Tracer for OpenGL ES

  and install version 23 doing this

  1. Select Help > Install New Software 
     2.Work with: p2repo - https://dl-ssl.google.com/android/eclipse/
  2. Select Developer Tools and Next
  3. Next, Accept the license agreement* and Finish

as mentioned here [[[This Android SDK requires ADT version 23.0.0 or above. Current version is 22.6. Please update ADT to the latest version?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24491193/this-android-sdk-requires-adt-version-23-0-0-or-above-current-version-is-22-6]])